# R flexdashboard reactive table output

Tags: r

Be gentle with me I haven't done this before.

I'm trying to create a dashboard to search for related information.

The search part is all working fine and as an r script it works, just having trouble getting this to work in a flexdashboard so it is a little easier to interact with. The issue is I need the query(search term) to respond from the search box to feed into the search process and then create a table output.

---

title: "Search Tool"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows

### vertical_layout: fill

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(DT)
library(quanteda)
library(shiny)
#https://www.r-bloggers.com/build-a-search-engine-in-20-minutes-or-less/
path <- "load in a dataset with some text information"
data <- read.csv(path)
data$Opened.Date <- as.Date(data$Opened.Date, origin = "1899-12-30")
doc.list <- as.character(data$Description)
N.docs <- length(doc.list)
names(doc.list) <- paste0("doc", c(1:N.docs))
```

### Row {}

```
textAreaInput("search", "Enter your search terms", placeholder = "Put your search terms in this text field",width = "400px")
```

```
{query <- renderText({ input$search})}
```

### Row {}

```
#In text mining and related fields, a corpus is a collection of texts, often with extensive manual annotation. Not surprisingly, the Corpus class is a fundamental data structure in tm.
my.docs <- VectorSource(c(doc.list, query))
my.docs$Names <- c(names(doc.list), "query")

my.corpus <- Corpus(my.docs)

#One of the nice things about the Corpus class is the tm_map function, which cleans and standardizes documents within a Corpus object. Below are some of the transformations.
#getTransformations()

#First, let's get rid of punctuation.
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removePunctuation)

#Use the stemDocument transformation to implement the famous Porter Stemmer algorithm. To use this particular transformation, first load the Snowball package.
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, stemDocument)

#remove numbers and white space, all lower case
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removeNumbers)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, tolower)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, stripWhitespace)

#One of the simplest things we can do is to count words within documents. This naturally forms a two dimensional structure, the term document matrix, with rows corresponding to the words and the columns corresponding to the documents. As with any matrix, we may think of a term document matrix as a collection of column vectors existing in a space defined by the rows. The query lives in this space as well, though in practice we wouldn't know it beforehand.
term.doc.matrix.stm <- TermDocumentMatrix(my.corpus)


#The matrices in tm are of type Simple Triplet Matrix where only the triples \( (i, j, value) \) are stored for non-zero values. To work directly with these objects, you may use install the slam [4] package. We bear some extra cost by making the matrix “dense” (i.e., storing all the zeros) below.
term.doc.matrix <- as.matrix(term.doc.matrix.stm) 


#cat("Dense matrix representation costs", object.size(term.doc.matrix), "bytes.\n", 
#    "Simple triplet matrix representation costs", object.size(term.doc.matrix.stm), 
#    "bytes.")

#We implement this weighting function across entire rows of the term document matrix, and therefore our tfidf function must take a term frequency vector and a document frequency scalar as inputs
get.tf.idf.weights <- function(tf.vec, df) {
  # Computes tfidf weights from a term frequency vector and a document
  # frequency scalar
  weight = rep(0, length(tf.vec))
  weight[tf.vec > 0] = (1 + log2(tf.vec[tf.vec > 0])) * log2(N.docs/df)
  weight
}

cat("A word appearing in 4 of 6 documents, occuring 1, 2, 3, and 6 times, respectively: \n", 
    get.tf.idf.weights(c(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6), 4))
## A word appearing in 4 of 6 documents, occuring 1, 2, 3, and 6 times, respectively: 
##  0.8074 1.615 2.087 0 0 2.894

#Using apply, we run the tfidf weighting function on every row of the term document matrix. The document frequency is easily derived from each row by the counting the non-zero entries (not including the query).
get.weights.per.term.vec <- function(tfidf.row) {
  term.df <- sum(tfidf.row[1:N.docs] > 0)
  tf.idf.vec <- get.tf.idf.weights(tfidf.row, term.df)
  return(tf.idf.vec)
}

tfidf.matrix <- t(apply(term.doc.matrix, c(1), FUN = get.weights.per.term.vec))
colnames(tfidf.matrix) <- colnames(term.doc.matrix)

#angle <- seq(-pi, pi, by = pi/16)
#plot(cos(angle) ~ angle, type = "b", xlab = "angle in radians", main = "Cosine similarity by angle")

tfidf.matrix <- scale(tfidf.matrix, center = FALSE, scale = sqrt(colSums(tfidf.matrix^2)))

query.vector <- tfidf.matrix[, (N.docs + 1)]
tfidf.matrix <- tfidf.matrix[, 1:N.docs]

doc.scores <- t(query.vector) %*% tfidf.matrix

results.df <- data.frame(doc = names(doc.list), score = t(doc.scores), text = unlist(doc.list))
#Join to original dataset and old code commented out
data$score <- results.df$score

#old results frames code commented out
#results.df <- results.df[order(results.df$score, decreasing = TRUE), ]
#results.df %>% select(doc, score, text) %>% top_n(20, wt = score) %>% datatable()
data$Relevance <- data$score
data <- data %>% arrange(desc(Relevance))
```

#### Search results

```
mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data)
  })
```